# Get latitude/longitude from service in onLocationChanged method

Tags: java, android, gps

I have a service which is called GPS_Service. *From another activity* I would like to start this service and get the value of location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude() from `onLocationChanged()` method. How could I do this, if `onLocationChanged()` is not static?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {

private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locManager;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    liveLocs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(GPS_Service
            .this).getString("len_live_locations", "-") != "-") {

    }

    listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            i.putExtra("coordinates", location.getLongitude() + "       " + location
                    .getLatitude());
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are plenty of examples in https://developer.android.com/ I suggest you to go there.

Comment: but could you tell me how I can call this method (onLocationChanged) from an other activity? I couldn't find it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)

Comment: @Marci the beauty of it is, you don't call onLocationChanged at all. instead, that is called by the LocationManager whenever the location of the android device has changed. in order to make that happen, you need to set your LocationListener instance on the LocationManager instance by calling requestLocationUpdates. there's an example of this here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your service: Try to use `Bundle`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("YourAction");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.put... // put extras you want to pass with broadcast. This is optional
bundle.putString("valueName", "The value you want in the activity");
bundle.putDouble("doubleName", someDouble);
intent.putExtras(bundle)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: "intent.putExtras(intent)" I don't understand this, why do you put intent in itself?

Comment: i think that's just a very minor mistake. instead of intent.putExtras(intent) it should be intent.putExtras(bundle)

Comment: I get it, thanks. But okay, this code snippet is in my onLocationChanged method. But how do I get the bundle from another activity?

Comment: @Marci you will need to set up a BroadcastReceiver in that Activity. See, for example, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#receiving_broadcasts  Also, let me second the use of LocalBroadcastManager (as Gowthaman recommends) instead of "sendBroadcast" as in the original code snippet. If your Activity and Service are in the same app, LocalBroadcastManager is all you need and it's more secure/private.

Comment: @Marci finally, I don't know your reasons for putting the LocationListener into a separate service, but ... maybe you should consider just putting your LocationListener directly into the Activity?

Answer (score 0):

This can get incredibly convoluted. You have to decide which type of location provider you will use, get the permissions, check if they have Google Play Services installed and the correct version needed and of course have fallback options for location manager vs fused location manager etc..

I have spent a lot of time writing libraries around monitoring location and it can get incredibly time consuming and maintenance can be a bit of a pain at times.

So here is what I would recommend. You mentioned "Service" I don't know if that is what you actually need or not, but you can do one of three things.

1. Manage location with a singleton wrapper
2. Create an IntentService to get your location that is within satisfactory accuracy to consider it done then broadcast receive your change using a custom broadcast receiver
3. Create a regular Android Service that can continue to update the location and feed it back to you as needed from the background where you would need to bind to this service and it is up to you to start and stop it. However, keep in mind there are restrictions on gathering locations in the background and may require a sticky notification in the taskbar now.

I suggest you start with a good library in a singleton wrapper with simple callbacks and then work your way into a service wrapper from there. I personally like this library for location updates.

https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib

works pretty well. Goodluck.